# append to the same list with multiprocessing - python

Tags: python, list, append, multiprocessing

I'd like different processes to append to the same list:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(n,L):
    a
    L.append(n)

pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
manager = mp.Manager()

L= manager.list()

l=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]

[pool.apply_async(foo, args=[n,L]) for n in l]
```

However,

```
>> print L
[]
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The problem was that there was traceback in my original code which wasn't printed on the screen. For example if I run the code above and `a` doesn't exist, the rest of the code isn't evaluated, but there is no exception raised. Is there a way to make multiprocessing print tracebacks so that I can debug the code?

Comment: `[pool.apply_async(foo, args=[n,L]) for n in l]` got `[<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x7ff72859c150>,
 <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x7ff72859c410>,
 <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x7ff72859c510>,
 <multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult at 0x7ff72859c590>]`, `print L` got `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]`
`,

Comment: Multiprocessing works more dependably, on more systems, if you put the multiprocessing code in a 'main' clause, as in all examples in the doc.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing

Comment: It seems the issue was that there was an error in my code but no traceback printed. I've edited my question

Answer (score 3):

Because you haven't waited tasks to finish.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(n,L):
    L.append(n)

pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
manager = mp.Manager()

L= manager.list()

l=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]

[pool.apply_async(foo, args=[n,L]) for n in l]
pool.close()
pool.join()
print(L)
```

Comment: @Straw: It seems the issue was that there was an error in my code, but no traceback printed. I've edited my question

Comment: you can debug your code by `pool.apply(...)`. This will run your code in blocking mode, and traceback will be printed.